# Reset the dynamic form as before

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events, reset

I have a html coding like this:

```
<form>
<table class="tabelWhiteJenisPembayaran">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" class="whiteJenisPembayaran" name="whiteJenisPembayaran[]" placeholder="Jenis Pembayaran" autocomplete="off" style="margin-bottom: 5px;"/></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Simpan</button>
<button class="btn" type="reset">Batal</button>
</form>
```

and I have a JavaScript coding as below:

```
$("table.tabelWhiteJenisPembayaran tbody tr:last").live('click', function(){
    var tr = '<tr><td><input type="text" class="whiteJenisPembayaran" name="whiteJenisPembayaran[]" autocomplete="off" style="margin-bottom: 5px;" placeholder="Jenis Pembayaran"/></td></tr>';
    $("table.tabelWhiteJenisPembayaran tbody").append(tr);                  
});
```

If the form is clicked will display a new form, for example I click 3 times in the last form, the total form there are 4 form. I'm wondering is how when I click on the "reset" the number of forms that had been there 4 form into 1 form as before. How to reset to 1 form again. Please help.

Comment: do you want to remove appended fields??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This way

```
$("table.tabelWhiteJenisPembayaran tbody tr:last").live('click', function(){
    var tr = '<tr><td><input type="text" class="whiteJenisPembayaran" name="whiteJenisPembayaran[]" autocomplete="off" style="margin-bottom: 5px;" placeholder="Jenis Pembayaran"/></td></tr>';
    $("table.tabelWhiteJenisPembayaran tbody").append(tr);                  
}); 

$("[type=reset]").click(function(){
     $('table.tabelWhiteJenisPembayaran tr:not(:first)').remove();
});
​
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uBu45/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you want. I guess you want to reset all the forms.

```
$('form').each(function(){
    this.reset()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you could clone the initial form element and its children and replace the form with the clone when the reset button is clicked.

here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/qZ6nK/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var formClone = null;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        formClone = $('table.tabelWhiteJenisPembayaran').parents('form').clone();
        $("table.tabelWhiteJenisPembayaran tbody tr:last").live('click', function(){
            var tr = '<tr><td><input type="text" class="whiteJenisPembayaran" name="whiteJenisPembayaran[]" autocomplete="off" style="margin-bottom: 5px;" placeholder="Jenis Pembayaran"/></td></tr>';
            $("table.tabelWhiteJenisPembayaran tbody").append(tr);                  
        }); 
    });
    function onReset(e) {
        var parent = $('table.tabelWhiteJenisPembayaran').parents('form').parent();
        $('table.tabelWhiteJenisPembayaran').parents('form').remove();
        parent.append(formClone);
        formClone = $('table.tabelWhiteJenisPembayaran').parents('form').clone();
    }
</script>

<form>
    <table class="tabelWhiteJenisPembayaran">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" class="whiteJenisPembayaran" name="whiteJenisPembayaran[]" placeholder="Jenis Pembayaran" autocomplete="off" style="margin-bottom: 5px;"/></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Simpan</button>
    <button class="btn" type="reset" onclick="onReset(event)">Batal</button>
</form>
```

Comment: thank you for respone my question and your answer is to help me and work. but it's too long, and thanks very much :)